# Does this formula make sense?

Tags: electromagnetism

As [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421613/what-does-this-formula-mean) was referred to this site and my image appears to relate to electrodynamics, I'm asking here whether Fluttershy's equation makes sense and whether it has a name. It's also partially visible in the title card of [*A Little Birdie Told Me*](https://www.discoverygo.com/my-little-pony-equestria-girls/a-little-birdie-told-me/):

[image: Fluttershy's equation from "A Little Birdie Told Me"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the equation is at least vaguely plausible, though one would need a bit more context to tell whether it's actually correct or not. (That is: it is plausible enough that it one can't say it's wrong without more context, which I guess is a good thing.)

The set at the top appears to be describing the [electrostatic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential) $\varphi$ created by an infinitely long charged wire, though some of the details don't look quite right.

The final system of equations seems to be describing the mutual capacitances of a set of conductors interacting electrostatically, but the fact that the right-hand sides don't have an index (say, $\varphi_i$ instead of $\varphi$) that varies with the $a_{ij}$ means that it can't be completely correct (and, therefore, that you shouldn't spend too much time scrutinizing it).